# OpenCL constant memory caching

Tags: memory, opencl

If I execute a kernel that uses a small piece of constant memory, then write to that constant memory while the kernel is running, does the kernel immediately see the change, or is the contents of the constant memory "cached" upon kernel launch - or does the OpenCL driver unconditionally delay the constant memory update until the kernel is done running?

If the first or third options occur, then how can I execute the same kernel with different constant memory data simultaneously? Do I need to create multiple kernel/constant buffer objects and work with that? Note I can't precalculate anything as kernel launches are a result of external signals that can occur at any time and rate. I could also create kernel objects on the fly, but that seems like an ugly solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fundamental concept in OpenCL that commands that are 'Enqueued' into the same command queue are executed in order. This includes `WriteBuffer` and similar commands. This means if you do

```
EnqueueNDKernalRange()
EnqueueWriteBuffer()
EnqueueNDKernalRange()
```

Then regardless of them being blocking or non-blocking, the write will only effect the second set of kernels.

If you're updating via a mapped pointer then it should be unmapped before any kernels run. Running kernels which access a buffer that is currently mapped is undefined (Spec 1.1 - Section 5.4.2.1).

As `EnqueueMapBuffer` and `EnqueUnmapMemObject` are also placed on the command queue, as long as you unmap the ordering of updates is still guaranteed.

Does that answer your question, or are you updating your buffer in another way?

> how can I execute the same kernel with different constant memory data simultaneously? Do I need to create multiple kernel/constant buffer objects and work with that?

Yes, multiple buffer objects.

Comment: Do I also need to create another kernel? Or can I launch two sets of kernels with different arguments (to change the buffer object) using the same kernel object? Basically I need an input value to my kernels to be synchronized across the whole system, yet I don't want the code to stall waiting for a kernel to finish running before starting another, and because I can predict what the input value should be updated to upon launching a kernel set I could potentially launch another set of kernels using the new input value.

Comment: You won't need another kernel just to change it's arguments. I must admit I'm a little confused by your description. It might be that you'll want to switch to `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE` which stops all ordering guarantees between enqueued commands, but then you have to do your own synchronisation. Alternatively having multiple command queues might give you the flexibility you need, or dividing the openCL device into sub-devices. It's difficult to know what's best without more detail of the application.

Comment: Ok I'll try to be more detailed. I want to run an application that provides an OpenCL-powered service to clients (via sockets/pipes). This service needs to be centralized, such that each client has a specific, unique ID, _which is then used in OpenCL calculations_. So let's say I have a client that connects to the application, it is given the ID "0" - this is passed to the OpenCL kernel, which is then launched, and the results are sent back to the client later. Meanwhile, another client connects, and is given the ID "1" - it needs its own kernel instance, and shouldn't have to wait [continued]

Comment: ... wait for the first client to be done before being able to launch its kernels. I don't think I can split the device since I don't know ahead of time how many clients will connect at any given time (and furthermore, I will be doing load-balancing, e.g. clients which require little work to be done will be transferred to the CPU device whereas clients which need high performance will get the GPU)

Comment: I'd probably be looking at using multiple command queues, 1 per client. You'd keep the natural in-order processing per queue which keeps the code simpler, but allows the OpenCL device to switch between queues if it's idle for some reason. Not sure whether you can create and destroy queues as clients connect/disconnect or whether you'd just have a pool of them.

Comment: That sounds like something that would work. I think I can work with a preallocated pool of command queues, since I want to keep the resources the service uses in check. This would work well with a thread pool architecture too. Thanks!